# MathJax-node to generate SVG output for inline TeX

Tags: node.js, svg, mathjax

Trying to convert simple inline equation into SVG isn't working and stops execution at the first occurrence of $.

Inline equation:

```
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to $(ax^2 + bx + c = 0)$ and they are $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
```

Code to convert the above inline-TeX to SVG:

```
var mjAPI = require("MathJax-node/lib/mj-single.js");
var fs = require('fs');

mjAPI.config({
    MathJax : {
        SVG : {
            scale: 120,
            font : "STIX-Web",
            linebreaks: { automatic: true },
            tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']] }
        }
    },
    displayErrors : true,
    displayMessages : false
});

mjAPI.start();

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], 'utf8', function (err, formula) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    mjAPI.typeset({
        math : formula,
        format : "inline-TeX",
        svg : true,
        width: 1,
        linebreaks: true
    }, function (results) {
        if (!results.errors) {
            console.log(results.svg)
        }
    });
});
```

Output:

Just prints *When* in svg.

Edited...

With Help of Peter Krautzberger (see his comments below), I was able to get the SVG export to work. Here is the code.

```
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node/lib/mj-page.js");
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;

var document = jsdom("When $a \\ne 0$, there are two solutions to $(ax^2 + bx + c = 0)$ and they are $x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$");

mjAPI.start();

mjAPI.typeset({
  html: document.body.innerHTML,
  renderer: "SVG",
  inputs: ["TeX"]
}, function(result) {
  "use strict";
  document.body.innerHTML = result.html;
  var HTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/^(\n|\s)*/, "");
  console.log(result.html);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mj-single` can only process single equations. For processing documents with multiple equations you'll need to use `mj-page` (which returns an HTML document and not a single svg).

Modifying the sample from [the readme](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/blob/master/README.md), this might get you started.

```
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node/lib/mj-page.js");
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var fs = require('fs');

var html = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])
var document = jsdom(html);

mjAPI.start();

mjAPI.typeset({
  html: document.body.innerHTML,
  renderer: "SVG",
  inputs: ["TeX"]
}, function(result) {
  console.log(result.html);
});
```

Comment: Note that mj-page is being removed from mathjax-node in favor of separate modules, cf https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/issues/206.

Comment: I am little lost! Haven;t been able to make mj-page.js work as well. What is the best approach to convert something like "When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to $(ax^2 + bx + c = 0)$ and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$" in an SVG.

Comment: Mathjax-node does not have functionality to convert an entire document into a single svg. It creates svgs for equations, with mjpage simplifying batch processing in a larger document.

Comment: But perhaps that is what you're looking for anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. I was able to get most of what I want. But the output still contains HTML like span elements etc., I am looking for something more of a simple output which contains only text and svg. Will post the code which I could get to work in the above question.